# Array of image button and textview in android

Tags: android, textview, imagebutton

I am trying to create an array in which each item will have an image button and below that image button will be a text view in center . Can anybody tell me how to do this. I tried the below code but not getting it worked

```
but=new ImageButton(this);
but.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
but.setId(1);
imbrelp= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
rel.addView(but,imbrelp);
tv= new TextView(this);
tvrelp= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
tvrelp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, but.getId());
tvrelp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, but.getId());
rel.addView(tv, tvrelp);
setContentView(rel);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid trying to create a RelativeLayout in code. It's going to be too messy for what you want to do. Instead, create an xml layout file for your individual item, and then inflate it for each item in your array.

Container layout in res/layout/main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/container"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Item layout in res/layout/item.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/image_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/my_image" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/image_button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/my_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.layout.container);

  LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

  Item[] items = getMyArrayOfItems();
  for (Item i : items) {
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, container, false);
    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_button);
    TextView textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);

    // TODO set the text and images

    container.addView(itemView);
  }
}
```